# F# arrays and match pattern

Tags: f#

I'm trying yo learn F# and arrays with recursion. I have solved summarizing an array with recursion now I'm trying to do the same thing except this time with match pattern but I can't get it to work help.

```
let myArray = Array.create 5 0

myArray.[0] <- 0
myArray.[1] <- 1
myArray.[2] <- 2
myArray.[3] <- 3
myArray.[4] <- 4

let rec sum (arr : int array) counter =
    if counter = 0 then 0
    else arr.[counter] + sum arr (counter - 1)

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Can't get this to work.

let rec sum1 (arr : int array) counter =
    match arr with
    | [||] -> printfn "0"
    | arr -> arr.[counter] + sum arr (counter - 1)
```

Comment: Isn't `sum1` supposed to be recursive? Do you mean to call `sum` from `sum1`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your implementation is that you expect immutable `arr` somehow changing from call to call to `sum1`. It does not change, so your implementation for anything, but empty array will be throwing `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`when `counter` gets negative!

Continue sticking to manipulation with the index:

```
let rec sum1 (arr : int array) counter =
    match counter with
    | 0 -> 0
    | _ -> arr.[counter - 1] + sum1 arr (counter - 1)
```

And `sum1 myarray (myarray.Length)` returns `10` as expected.

This implementation is not perfect as well as your first one `sum` with `if-then-else`. To understand why just try running it with something like `let myarray = Array.init 100000 id` - it will likely throw `System.Stackoverflow` exception. Cause of exception - it is not [tail-recursive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/08/07/understanding-tail-recursion.aspx).

Making it tail-recursive is not difficult - just add an accumulator `sum` that fully unties subsequent calls stack-wise:

```
let rec sum1TR sum counter (arr: int[]) =
    match counter with
    | 0 -> sum
    | _ -> sum1TR (sum + arr.[counter - 1]) (counter - 1) arr
```

Now `sum1TR 0 1000000 (Array.init 1000000 id)` works even for an array of a million items.

Finally, as you want to get a sum of array's elements it make sense to expose to end user only single parameter - the array per se, moving recursive `summator` inside the external function:

```
let sum (as: int[]) =
    let rec summator s l =
        match l with
        | 0 -> s
        | _ -> summator (s + as.[l - 1]) (l - 1)
    summator 0 as.Length
```